# UNITY: How to make the UNITY preview look like an android portrait

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I usually develope apps for android with visual studio, but i want to increase my programming knowledge a little and am trying into game development.

I watched some tutorials and get everything to debug on my phone, but I have one major question ahead of me, before I can really start:

So, in Visual Studio I usually deliever 5 different hdpi folders, and work with linearlayouts and set weights which work as some form of percentage towards the users screen. With this technique, the apps that I build usually look more or less the same on every android device out there (which indeed are  LOT).

If I come to unity now, I'd like to set the preview window of my mobile game to already be in a portrait format. Which would be some kind of 90 degree 16:9 ratio. I can bring it to 16:9 ratio but, again this is always landscape and never portrait. But that means that I kind of need to guess what the game will look like when finished - and that is a no go!

So how could I achieve what I need? Sort of tilt the 16:9 ratio over by 90 degrees. 
I hope I made myself clear!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks, I kinda found a way just by playing around with it.
Where it said "16:9" right above the preview screen. When clicking on it and then clicking on this little "+" i could manually provide a resolution such as 1440 x 2560. This brought it into portrait android mode. THANKS :)